# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Reported by many but problem seems to be different:

In one of my device, the application crashes on click of a button with the following log-

```
01-14 19:50:51.284: V/Provider/Setting(31765): invalidate [system]: current 397 != cached 0
01-14 19:50:51.363: W/ResourceType(31765): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-14 19:50:51.365: D/AndroidRuntime(31765): Shutting down VM
01-14 19:50:51.365: W/dalvikvm(31765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d12258)
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1036)
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2140)
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765):    at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:924)
01-14 19:50:51.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31765):    at com.palash.main.Popper.setRules(Popper.java:869)
```

**Popper.java:**

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("xml/" + rule_file, "string", getActivity().getPackageName());

XmlPullParser xpp0 = getResources().getXml(resId); //Line 869
XMLData xml = new XMLData(xpp0);
```

**NOTE:**

The application gives a HUD that says `"Unfortunately, Palash has stopped"` and then gives two options, `"Free Space"` and `"OK"`.

Pressing the OK button places me on the Home screen of the device and the Free Space button places me on the Settings application on the device.

Comment: "xml/" + rule_file -> rule_file (if that identifier does exists and does refer to a string, of course)

Comment: Well its pretty obvious - resource with identifier resId was not found.

Comment: @smitalm - That is right but the same code is working on my other device. That is, the `resId` is found. How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIdentifier()` returns 0 of the given resource was not found, and 0 is not a valid resource identifier.

You should check for `resId != 0` before calling `getXml()`.

And then figure out why the `rule_file` resource is not found - there's insufficient information in the question for that.

Comment: Understood does this problem may also occur if 1) Either there is no free space on a device OR 2) The application built is not proper i.e. you need to rebuild the application by `Clean` ? I am asking because the same code is working on my other device.

Comment: There could be some deeper problem, but the `resId == 0` is the most obvious and needs to be excluded first.